# iAds on developer device not showed, after "ready for sale" still developer modus

Tags: iphone, release, iad, jailbreak

My App "insect scare" is ready for sale since last night. It has one iAd at the bottom.
After the state was changed to "ready for sale" I removed all the provisioning profiles, reinstalled the app and rebooted several times. The iAd banner works on other devices, just doesnt on my developer device. I only see the "Test Advertisement" Banner on the developer device. Has anyone any more ideas? Is it possible that it has something to do with a jailbreak? I jailbroke this device (4.3.3 jailbreakme.com), just to use SBsettings. But I can see other commercial banners from other apps. Thanks in advance, Fabi

Answer (score 0):

iAds will only work when the apps are installed from the App Store.

Is this the case?

Comment: Yes I removed everything and installed it from the app store